# Email Design: Text over background image

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, email-templates

Am am trying to create a header for an email that has a background image and text centered over it. This is how it looks in "normal" email clients:

[image]

However in outlook it doesn't quit work, it ends up like this:

[image]

Are there any email gurus that can help me fix this?

Here is what I have so far (built in react):

```
<table width="640" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" align="center" style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td
            height="143"
            width="640"
            align="center"
            valign="middle"
            background="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/website-header-banner-design-abstract-260nw-1621024345.jpg"
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#00A699', backgroundSize: 'cover' }}
        >
            <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `<!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:640px;height:143px">
                          <v:fill type="frame" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/website-header-banner-design-abstract-260nw-1621024345.jpg" />
                          <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0" style="v-text-anchor:middle">
                          <![endif]-->`,
                }}
            />
            <table
                cellPadding="0"
                cellSpacing="0"
                className="arb_w100 "
                align="center"
                style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}
            >
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <td
                            align="center"
                            valign="bottom"
                            className="arb_headline_1"
                            style={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}
                        >
                                            <span
                                                style={{
                                                    fontSize: '22px',
                                                    fontWeight: 400,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                                                    lineHeight: '28px',
                                                    color: '#ffffff',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                For a limited time, take
                                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `<!--[if gte mso 9]>
                          </v:textbox>
                        </v:rect>
                      <![endif]-->`,
                }}
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the code from above translated to standard HTML:

```
<table width="640" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="143" width="640" align="center" valign="middle"
            background="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/website-header-banner-design-abstract-260nw-1621024345.jpg"
            style="background-color:#00A699;background-size:cover">
            <div><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:640px;height:143px">
                          <v:fill type="frame" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/website-header-banner-design-abstract-260nw-1621024345.jpg" />
                          <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0" style="v-text-anchor:middle">
                          <![endif]--></div>
            <table cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" className="arb_w100 " align="center" style="margin:0 auto">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <td align="center" valign="bottom" className="arb_headline_1" style="padding-top: 10px;"><span
                            style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 28px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">For a limited time, take</span>
                        </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                          </v:textbox>
                        </v:rect>
                      <![endif]--></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey there, can you please swap the current snippet with the final HTML on send? Difficult to debug when we can't see what React is generating in the final instance. It could be that there is an issue with your VML (Outlook) code, so seeing the final code is more helpful.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein sure, just added the raw HTML below it

Comment: Is this possible without centering the overlayed text?  I have a need for the same thing but I need to position TWO different dynamic text values over an image.  Not in the center, but in an exact location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for supplying the final HTML, that helped a lot!

So you've got a couple of issues with your final HTML.

1. You have divs wrapping each of the MSO snippets which essentially closes off and breaks the snippets. So remove the closing div tag for the first MSO snippet and the opening div tag for the second snippet.
2. You'll need need to shift these two tags in, so it is only wrapping your inner content. We usually add a div to wrap the inner content to help reset the HTML in Outlook and then we can set whatever styles etc in the inner content.
3. I then noticed you've got a double up of the inner  tags. Remove the outer  tags as they don't have any styles declared, whereas the inner one does.

Amending those small things will fix your issue.

Here is the snippet cleaned up in case my instructions don't make sense:

```html
<table width="640" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="143" width="640" align="center" background="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/website-header-banner-design-abstract-260nw-1621024345.jpg" style="background-color:#00A699;background-size:cover">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:640px;height:143px">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/website-header-banner-design-abstract-260nw-1621024345.jpg" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0" style="v-text-anchor:middle">
            <![endif]-->
            <div>
            <table cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" className="arb_w100 " align="center" style="margin:0 auto">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" className="arb_headline_1" style="padding-top: 10px;"><span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 28px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">For a limited time, take</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```